# Is there any way to parameter Jess in a way it will never much variables with different names in the same rule?

Tags: java, rule-engine, jess

I explain my question by Example.

```
(deftemplate point (slot a)(slot b))
```

```
(assert (point (a 1)(b 1)))    
(assert (point (a 1)(b 2)))    
(assert (point (a 2)(b 2)))
```

I want to get all possible Points with avoiding Points with the same a and b values. (No [a,b] = [1,1] v [2,2] v ..)

```
(defrule r1    
(point (a ?x)(b ?y))    
(test (neq ?x ?y))    
=>    
(printout t "Point (a = " ?x ")(b = " ?y ")" crlf))
```

```
Point (a = 1)(b = 2)
```

Good!

***To optimize performance :*** i want to avoid passing by The 'test' conditional element. (test (neq ?x ?y))

***So is there any way to parameter the engine in a way it will never much variables with different names in the same rule?***

The aim is to use..

```
(defrule r1
(point (a ?x)(b ?y))
=>
(printout t "Point (a = " ?x ")(b = " ?y ")" crlf))
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to write this rule would be like this:

```
(defrule r1    
  (point (a ?x)(b ?y&~?x))    
  =>    
  (printout t "Point (a = " ?x ")(b = " ?y ")" crlf))
```

Comment: Thanks Ernest for answering :) 
Well The way you propose { (point (a ?x)(b ?y&~?x)) } will not helps me. Because my fact-templates can contain many slots. And also my rules contains many facts in the Left-Hand-Side.
Do you have any idea about my main question?

Comment: @Chihab No, there's no way to do what you describe. You would have to express all your constraints explicitly.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill Occasionally I cannot resist to do a few minutes of programming in Jess. Regards!

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the Jess API if the standard set of functions isn't sufficient. Thus it is possible to write a reflection-style function that computes a complex property of a fact.

```
; define an additional template for storing the property for a point
(deftemplate point (slot a)(slot b)(slot c)(slot d))
(deftemplate attr (slot point)(slot isdiff))

; define a function computing whether all slots are different
(deffunction alldiff (?factid)
  (bind ?res TRUE)
  (bind ?lov (create$))
  (foreach ?slot (((engine) findDeftemplate "point") getSlotNames)
    (bind ?v (fact-slot-value ?factid ?slot))
    (if (member$ ?v ?lov) then (bind ?res FALSE) (break)
                          else (bind ?lov (create$ ?lov ?v)))
  )
  (return ?res)
)

; one rule to create the attr fact for a point
(defrule createattr
  ?point <- (point)
  (not (attr (point ?point)))
=>
  (bind ?isdiff (alldiff ?point))
  (assert (attr (point ?point)(isdiff ?isdiff)))
)

; rule using the attr fact where slot isdiff is TRUE
(defrule useattr
  ?point <- (point (a ?a)(b ?b)(c ?c)(d ?d))
  (attr (point ?point)(isdiff TRUE))
=>
  (printout t "a=" ?a ", b=" ?b ", c=" ?c ", d=" ?d crlf)
)

; test
(deffacts insp
  (point (a 1)(b 2)(c 3)(d 4))
  (point (a 1)(b 1)(c 3)(d 4))
  (point (a 1)(b 2)(c 2)(d 4))
  (point (a 1)(b 2)(c 3)(d 3))
)
(reset)
(run)
```

Output:

```
Jess> (batch different.clp)
a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4
5
```